# Making raster histogram excluding zeros in R?

Tags: raster, r, histogram, plot

In R, can I make a histogram of all the non-zero values in my raster?

Some reproducible data below. I just want the histogram to be made with the zeros. Happy with a way to do that, or I guess to create a new raster that just removes all the zero-cells from r.

````
y=seq(33,34,.1)
coords=expand.grid(x,y)
rdf=data.frame(coords,depth=runif(nrow(coords),0,2))
names(rdf)=c('x','y','value')
r=rasterFromXYZ(rdf)
plot(r)
hist(r)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an assignment for `x` in the code above so I can't generate your exact output, but you should be able to plot non-0 entries in your histogram by using `hist(r[r!=0])`.

Here's an assignment for `x` (just a placeholder) and some artificially-crafted 0's for the raster values that demonstrate the difference between `hist(r)` and `hist(r[r!=0])`:

```
x = seq(-1,1,.1)
y=seq(33,34,.1)
coords=expand.grid(x,y)
rdf=data.frame(coords,depth=runif(nrow(coords),0,2))
names(rdf)=c('x','y','value')
rdf$value[23:30] = 0 #Added a few 0's to the value column
r=rasterFromXYZ(rdf)
plot(r)
hist(r)
hist(r[r!=0]) # Note reduction in count for lowest bin
```